# UWP Jump List Exception

Tags: uwp

I am using this example.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/JumpList

But when I add an item to the jumplist, a exception was thrown as follow, I don't know what is to be accessed and why the access is denied.
[image]

The System info and VS info:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue, did you modify the code in this sample? If not, could you please tell us the steps we need to follow in order to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Thank you. I do NOTHING about the code. It is problem with my win10 system setting, because I try to deploy the Release Build Result to A new Win10( In VMware) It runs correctly. But when I deploy the result in current Machine It exit when click the Add button(Which raise the exception). My computer only has the Windows Defender as anti-virus software. What a strange problem.